# Re-render component when state changes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having a state which is bound to some input types:

```
 const [unit, setUnit] = useState('1');
 const [value, setValue] = useState('1');
```

I am passing these as props to a functional component like this:

```
<ComponentButton props={[unit, value]} />
```

This in turn calls the downstream async API calls to servers for execution. I would like to re-render this buttonComponent(which is a functional one) every time a state is changed. Currently it is just rendering the first or default values, where as Ideally it should take the values dynamically from inputs as to state.

If you have a better approach kindly suggest.

Comment: you need to update the state value using setUnit or setValue this will trigger re-render

Answer (score 0):

You pass the state as an array, it could lead to not re-evaluate the child component because it is a reference type not a value type.

I would suggest to pass the state as a separate props.

Example:

```
<ComponentButton unit={unit} value={value} />
```